# How to Lock folder programmatically in android?

Tags: android, directory, file-permissions

It is possible to lock a folder as password protected programmatically?

http://developer.android provides **File-lock** but I want to **Lock folder** not a File.

Android operating system is totally based on Linux kernel and Linux kernel provides permission to access folder or file. but how can I change permission to Lock folder.

Comment: How is it done anti-grammatically?

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the permissions of a file or filer on SDcard. You can change permissions of file or folders on rooted phones on locations where ext2 or romfs, or similar filesystem is used. But I don't think that this is what you want. On Linux you can't modify permissions on nfts or fat filesystems also.